# How do I sort a JSON array by value that is nested array[].Level1.Level2

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I need to sort a JSON array by a value which is nested. Here is the routine I am using and it always returns `0`.  The field value I want to sort on is `advancedoptions.storeId`.

```
orders.sort(GetSortOrder("advancedOptions.storeId"));

function GetSortOrder(prop) {  
    return function(a, b) {  
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {  
            return 1;  
        } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

I want to sort the JSON by storeId:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "orderId": 415354051,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 415172626,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 375780
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 414286558,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 412403726,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Correct sort order should be:

```
"orderId": 415172626,
"orderId": 415354051,
"orderId": 414286558,
"orderId": 412403726,
```

Comment: FYI, JSON is a *textual representation of an object* (the result of Serialization). What you have here is an object, or a Javascript object if you want; there are no JSON objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function GetSortOrder(select) {
  return function(a, b) {
    const propA = select(a);
    const propB = select(b);
    if (propA > propB) {
      return 1;
    } else if (propA < propB) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
}

const orders = [
  { advancedOptions: { storeId: 34 } },
  { advancedOptions: { storeId: 342 } },
  { advancedOptions: { storeId: 3 } },
];

orders.sort(GetSortOrder(function (i) { return i.advancedOptions.storeId }));

console.log(orders);
```

Comment: This code is for a google app script which supports ES5. I cannot use the arrow function technique (which I am not familiar with) what would this look like in the old Function expression way?

Answer (score 0):

It's the prop you're passing in, you can't access a nested property in an object how you're doing it `a["advancedOptions.storeId"]`. You need to do something like `a["advancedOptions"]["storeId"]`. The reason why your function always returns 0 is because `a["advancedOptions.storeId"]` is always returning `undefined` not satisfying your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't access nested properties when using the bracket notation `object[property]`. You need to apply brackets for each layer of nesting, like `object[property][propery]`. When you're calling `a[advancedOptions.storeId]`, it is returning undefined, as the correct syntax to access storeId using the bracket notation is `a[advancedOptions][storeId]`.

If you only need to sort by one property, why not use:

`orders.sort((a, b) => a.advancedOptions.storeId > b.advancedOptions.storeId)`

Comment: This code is for a google app script which supports ES5.  I cannot use the arrow function technique (which I am not familiar with) what would this look like in the old Function expression way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to have the data sorted by `storeId`

```
ordersData.orders.sort((a,b) => 
      a.advancedOptions.storeId < b.advancedOptions.storeId ? -1 : a.advancedOptions.storeId > b.advancedOptions.storeId ? 1 : 0
    );
```

```js
var ordersData = {
    "orders": [
        {
            "orderId": 415354051,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 415172626,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 375780
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 414286558,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        },
        {
            "orderId": 412403726,
            "advancedOptions": {
                "storeId": 376480
            }
        }
    ]
}
ordersData.orders.sort((a,b) => 
  a.advancedOptions.storeId < b.advancedOptions.storeId ? -1 : a.advancedOptions.storeId > b.advancedOptions.storeId ? 1 : 0
);
console.log(ordersData);
```